# how do i que calls with twilio studio so i can put callers in a que then anser when the line is free?

Tags: twilio

how do I queue calls with studio, so i can put callers in a queue if I'm on the phone once I reach 3 callers in a queue it would send them to a voice mailbox? I can see the enqueue function but not sure how to use it fully.

When a call comes in a can make it play a message then I would like it to be passed to the call queue if I'm on the phone.

Also, do I need 4 phone numbers for 3 lines or is there a way to just use one number and have extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Enqueue widget will send a call into a [TaskRouter workflow](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter). I recommend you take a look into the [TaskRouter documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter) to find out what you can achieve with that. It is a fully featured call router that you can program to work the way you want.

Studio provides the Say/Play widget for you to play messages to callers.

A Twilio number can receive more than one call simultaneously and you can use the Gather input on Call widget to build extension like functionality.